# TSQL: Get sales data for each hour

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am currently using the below code to get sales data from my database. The problem with it is that it will not show 0 for those hours that there were no sales in. I don't mind hard coding the hours but I can't find a way to do it that way. So,

1.st Question: How can I ammend the below code to display 0 for hours that had no sales within,

2.nd Question: How can I get an ordered list out of it. The below code would place 9:00 - 10:00 to the end of the list since it is not two digits..

```
-- HOUR BASED SALES
select (CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, INSERTDATE) as varchar(255)) + ':00 -' +
        CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, INSERTDATE) as varchar(255)) + ':59'
       ) as [time],
       SUM (TOTAL) as REVENUE,
       COUNT (RECEIPTID) AS TOTAL_SALES,
       DEPOTID
From INVOICE INV
WHERE DEPOTID IN (25) AND TRANSDATE BETWEEN '20181025' AND '20181025'
Group By cast(datepart(hour, INSERTDATE) AS VARCHAR(255)), DEPOTID
ORDER BY CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, INSERTDATE) AS VARCHAR(255))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list the hours and use `left join`:

```
select (cast(v.hh as varchar(255)) + ':00 -' +
        cast(v.hh as varchar(255)) + ':59'
       ) as [time],
       sum(TOTAL) as REVENUE,
       sum(RECEIPTID) AS TOTAL_SALES,
       depot
From (values (0), (1), . . . (23)
     ) v(hh) left join
     invoice i
     on datepart(hour, i.insertdate) = v.hh and
        i.depotid in (25) and
        i.transdate between '20181025' and '20181025'
group by v.hh, DEPOTID
order by v.hh
```

Comment: Thanks. apart from the issue where instead of v.insertdate its only insertdate, it works well!. Can you also let me know what is KeithL is saying about the "outer apply" ?

Comment: @KemalEmin . . . You can use `outer apply` instead of `left join`.  However, `left join` is the more traditional approach.